# What routing protocol does linux use by default?

Tags: debian, routing

I know that there are multiple routing protocols (BGP and so on), but which one does linux use when I'm connected to my home network? I'm using a debian based system.

Comment: BGP has no use in a local network.

Comment: I know when BGP is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main sides to routing: the first is how packets are routed, the second is how the system knows how to route packets.

I’m not sure the first has a name (at least, I don’t know one). The Linux kernel maintains a routing table, which is a list of subnets associated with a network interface, optionally a gateway, a metric and various other options. When your system sends a packet, the kernel looks at its routing tables; if one or more entries describe a subnet containing the packet’s destination, the kernel sends it to the corresponding network or gateway; otherwise, it goes to the default gateway. You can see the routing tables by running

```
ip route
```

(which will show the main table entries) and

```
ip route table local
```

(which will show the local table entries) or

```
ip route table all
```

(which will show everything).

You should see at least entries like

```
default via 100.65.64.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
100.65.64.0/21 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 100.65.67.24 metric 600
```

This says that packets to 100.65.64.0/21 (the subnet I’m on) are to be sent *via* `wlp3s0`, and packets to anything which doesn’t match a routing table entry are to be sent to 100.65.64.1 (the default gateway).

There are multiple algorithms for the second part. BGP is one, but you’d normally only see that on AS routers. In typical home setups the routing tables are populated using information from [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) on IPv4 or [NDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbor_Discovery_Protocol) on IPv6.

Routing table entries can also be added without necessarily corresponding to information from a well-known protocol; for example, entries for container networks are generally added directly by your container runtime.

Comment: I believe the name of that routing scheme is TCP/IP. And that is the only one for the Internet we use today.

Comment: @Isaac hah yes, I was trying to think of something more specific ;-).

Comment: That means Linux does not use any routing protocol by default, doesn‘t it?